# What defines an "objective"?

Tags: lens, terminology, optics

I'm not experienced in photography and would like to get some knowledge about the terminology.

My question is: What defines an *objective*? Or: When would you define something as an *objective*?

I mean, would you still call it an objective even when there are no lenses in it? I know this example might not make sense. Just imagine an "objective" has several apertures and/or filters.

I hope this makes sense somehow.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't open the Link due to 400 Bad Request. Did you mean [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective_(optics))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, an objective lens is a lens which converges light to produce what's called a "real image" — a projection that can be observed on a screen, or (as in the case of camera) recorded on film or a sensor.

Binoculars and microscopes have objective lenses which converge the light and then *also* eyepiece lenses which diverge it again.

A stack of glass or apertures which does not produce such an image is not an objective lens. In fact, without a curved surface, you don't really have a *lens* at all, let alone an objective lens (and the term "objective" in this context is really just short for "objective lens").

In conversational English in the context of photography, we generally call the thing that screws to the front of a camera body a "lens", not an "objective". We even do that when the "lens" in question contains mirrors — we say "a mirror lens". Or, even though it's not technically a lens at all, we say "pinhole lens".

Comment: @MoeJo Yes. It's my understanding that "Objektiv" is the common word for a photographic lens in German — is this correct? In English (American English, at least), we say "lens" and while I understand "objective" as a synonym it's a technical term to me, not one I'd expect a non-photographer to understand.

Comment: @mattdm Yes, we in the German speaking world say "Objektiv" - the only other term you hear is "Glas" ('glass'), but I only heard it about three times in 15 years. I sometimes say "Linse" ('lens'), but only because I read a lot in English and so it's because my mind is still in English-mode ;-) _Note that [Wiki's article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_lens) starts with "A camera lens (also known as photographic lens or photographic objective)"!_

Comment: To my knowledge as a native speaker, "Objektiv" (noun) is only used to mean '(photographic) lens' - the English noun 'objective' would roughly translate as "Ziel" ('goal'). The adjective "objektiv" is the same as the adjective 'objective' in English.

Comment: Note that some objectives are made with mirrors, and may or may not have lenses.
Although, most of the time "objective" and "lens" may be synonyms.

Comment: @vsis That's a good point, although because language is messy and frustrating, we deal with that by saying "mirror lens" or "pinhole lens". Technically not correct, but that's never stopped English. :)

Comment: There is also a (disappearing) usage, at least in American English, among the photographic community where "the objective" of a complex lens system with multiple elements/groups is a reference to the front/first element or group where light enters the lens. For example, : "A 300mm f/4 lens must have an *objective* at least 75mm in diameter." This usage was probably more true of prime lenses, where the front element was the converging lens and most everything behind it were for corrective purposes. That's not as much the case with many modern internal zoom or internal focus lenses.

Comment: @MichaelC Yeah, I've heard that too. I think it's likely that this is actually a misunderstanding/confusion with the objective/eyepiece distinction in a virtual image system like a telescope or binoculars.

Comment: I've seen a few older photography textbooks that use it that way with regard to photographic lenses. It may be a case of the *physics* community and the *photographic* community having different meanings for the same word(s). Like, for example, "[focal plane](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/45970/15871)."